# Hidden troubles with not using JSON, and using Datatables?

Tags: c#, design, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am currently working on a solution that involves showing millions (a hundred,  maybe more) of records from a database, but only a small subset per page (maybe 20-30 records a page)

- The site has been created as a WebForms application
- Database is Intersystems Cache, (luckily the SQL side only, no globals)

  - Intersystems Cache comes with a CacheClient.dll, that functions like System.Data.SQLClient but for intersystems cache.
- Team has determined that we use JQuery.BootGrid as the grid, since it is open source and highly functional
- I want the solution to follow good design, as it is a trait that I want to have as a software developer.

I am able to create the JSON file from C#, via JSON.Net. However I am having trouble actually consuming the JSON file since the format is different:

JSON.net format:

```
[{"NickName":"Bob","LogIN":"6/7/1846 12:00:00 AM","LogOUT":"6/7/1846 12:00:00 AM"},{"NickName":"Bob","LogIN":"6/6/1846 12:00:00 AM","LogOUT":"6/6/1846 12:00:00 AM"},{"NickName":"Patrick","LogIN":"6/7/1846 12:00:00 AM","LogOUT":"6/7/1846 12:00:00 AM"},{"NickName":"Ward","LogIN":"6/7/1846 12:00:00 AM","LogOUT":"6/7/1846 12:00:00 AM"},{"NickName":"Ward","LogIN":"6/6/1846 12:00:00 AM","LogOUT":"6/6/1846 12:00:00 AM"},{"NickName":"Ward","LogIN":"6/5/1846 12:00:00 AM","LogOUT":"6/5/1846 12:00:00 AM"},{"NickName":"Krabs","LogIN":"","LogOUT":""},{"NickName":"Sandy","LogIN":"","LogOUT":""},{"NickName":"Pearl","LogIN":"","LogOUT":""}]
```

jquery-bootgrid JSON required format:

```
    {
  "current": 1,
  "rowCount": 5,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "a0e3a286-4343-4240-8d6d-e79fa2e94b4c",
      "sender": "test@test.de",
      "received": "2014-04-17 15:08:03Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "dd9f2d42-9442-404c-8d2a-dd3bd2156c03",
      "sender": "test@test.de",
      "received": "2014-04-16 15:19:31Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "e9b8ede5-c1bf-4d90-b724-e7379b25f7b3",
      "sender": "test@test.de",
      "received": "2014-04-16 15:17:05Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "153d3acb-efe7-4b5f-a3a9-e8ac18bdec30",
      "sender": "test@test.de",
      "received": "2014-04-16 15:17:05Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "49bad60a-bbf7-42bf-b040-d901805ccbf1",
      "sender": "test@test.de",
      "received": "2014-04-15 11:23:06Z"
    }
  ],
  "total": 5
}
```

Now, I tried googling for solutions and tutorials for using asp.net with jquery-bootgrid, and [I found this solution which makes use of the `GridView` control](https://dotnetco.de/use-jquery-bootgrid-with-asp-net-gridview/)

From the link, I imagine I can fill the gridview with datareader or pass a datatable (containing CacheSQL results) as it's datasource and apply the formatting mentioned to make use of the Jquery-BootGrid

however, is this applicable as a good design? Is this actually a bad idea, and should I stick to finding a way to consume the JSON file instead? 
Should we rethink about using Jquery-bootgrid? I know there is an alternative JQuery grid, but it is not free.

Comment: [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) is also free alternative

Answer (score 2):

> I am currently working on a solution that involves showing millions (a hundred, maybe more) of records from a database

If that's *really* what you mean, then ...

Why???

What is the Poor Soul sitting in front of that screen ever going to *do* with them all?  Basic User Interface design guidelines would recommend 5 items, plus-or-minus two, as being optimal for Users.  "Millions"?  Don't even think about it.

Shifting a million of *anything* across the network is going to be cripplingly slow and trying to format all of them in the client browser will take a real *brute* of a machine - that your End User may not have.

Of course, if what you *actually* mean is that you have a database *containing* millions of records and you're displaying [small] *subsets* of them, please disregard the above.

Comment: I apologize, I meant containing millions, but showing a subset of them in a grid pagination.